# Unable to import Instagram.util

Tags: android, instagram-api

I am trying to make an Android application connected with Instagram, when trying to add:

```
import instagram.image.ImageLoader;
import instagram.util.Constants;
import instagram.util.InstagramApp;
```

It saids "Cannot resolve symbol", how can I add them?

I'm using Android Studio

Comment: Does the Instagram Guides not tell you how to add Gradle dependencies?

Comment: Not that I know anything but I think you need to add the Instagram library in File --> Project Structure